# Remove the last X files of a directory

Tags: linux, command-line, rm

In colab, I have unzip a file, but now there is too much files in the directory according to the colab's setup. Is there a command line to remove the last x files of a directory?

I know I can remove all the files from this repository with `rm -rf *`, but I just want to remove for instance the last 100 files of the repository.

Comment: What do you mean by "last"?  Do you want to sort by name, mtime, size, or some other metric?

Answer (score 0):

Try globing or better REGEX.

The most easy way is with globing you use the star * and some differentiation example: `rm *.txt` # will delete all files that end with **.txt** or `rm document*.local` # will delete all files which start with **document** and end with **.local**

The better wey is searching files by attribut and executing command on the result but is a bit complex to explain so check this out.
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-how-to-find-and-remove-files/

Answer (score 0):

Using a shell array and parameter expansion:

```sh
all_files=(*)
printf '%s\n' "${all_files[@]: -100}" | nl
#rm "${all_files[@]: -100}"
```

Uncomment the last line if it looks like the correct list of files to delete.

The space between the colon and the minus sign is required to disambiguate from another form of parameter expansion.

Ref: [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)